# How change duration of composition after effects (extensions)

Tags: after-effects

I have a composition with a facebook message, it lasts for 10 seconds.
[image]
I dont have aly slider to change the duration of the beginning\edning neither can I change the overall duration of it.  There is no code representing that. I couldnt find any parameter to change the duration...
Is there any way to change it. Because otherwise all these extensions packs with presets are useless if Im tied tightly to timing
[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the description I'm not 100% sure of the composition setup you are going for.
However, in similar situations I've found that precomposing all of the layers can help. This would mean selecting all the layers you'd like to include, right click, precompose.
You can then change the in/out points of the composition as a whole.